# xgboost rank pairwise what is the prediction input and output

Tags: xgboost

I'm trying to use XGBoost to predict the rank for a set of features for a given query. I managed to train a model it but I'm confused around the input data when I ask for a prediction.

I'm trying to understand if I'm doing something wrong or this is not the right approach.

**What I'm doing:**

1. I parse the training data ([see here a sample](https://notepad.pw/6b7yn1a2)) and feed it in a DMatrix such that the first column represents the quality-of-the-match and the following columns are the scores on different properties and also send the docIds as labels
2. I configure the group sizes

The training seems to work fine, I get not errors, and I use the rank:pairwise objective

For prediction, I use a fake entry with fake scores (1 row, 2 columns [see here](https://notepad.pw/y3m6bm17)) and I get back a single float value.

I'm trying to understand:

**1. Do I need to feed in a label for the prediction ?**

My understanding is that labels are similar to "doc ids" so at prediction time I don't see why I need them

**2. Do I need to set the group size when doing predictions ? And if so, what does it represent ?**

My understanding is that groups are for training data to assist ranking "per query". How does that correlate with predictions? Do I set a group size anyway?

**3. How do I correlate the "group" from the training with the prediction?**

How do I figure out the pair (score, group) from the result of the prediction, given I only get back a single float value - what group is that prediction for?